# Can you add number padding to a bootstrap number input box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4

If I'm using an input box, like so:

`<input type="number" class="form-control" value="00001" />`

How can I make it so that when pressing the arrow up, it changes to *00002* instead of *2*?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"00001" or "00002" are not numbers, but if you still wanna do it, think something like:

Function to add leading zeros at left (num is value, size is the size of the string)

```
function padLeadingZeros(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Then:

```
$(function() {
      $("input").change(function(e){ // If the value changes
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(padLeadingZeros($(this).val(), 5)); //replace the value with the returned value of the function, 5 is size.
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't use this exact code, but I did use the idea.  I was hoping there was some sort of formatting option I wasn't aware of.